# Training in tensor flow cpu version too slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, training-data

I have installed Tensorflow cpu version.I have only few images as dataset and I am training on a machine with 4GB ram and Core i5 3340m 2.70GHZ with batch size 1 and it is still extremely slow.the size of all images is same (200X185 i think).Will it train like this ? kindly tell me how can I speed up this process?

[Training porcess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROnyO.png)

Comment: What do you mean "Will it train..."? It is currently training in the image you provided. Model training is definitely not a _quick_ thing. Without code, an example of what you're trying to achieve, or any specific questions I'm not sure that this fits on SO.

Comment: maximum 120 second per epoch is not too long, I usually wait several days to only train a model

Answer (score 1):

If your network is deep, it could take a long time to train your network using CPU as it is not optimized like GPU for calculations.

I would suggest you to get a graphic card, even a old version of graphic card can significantly improve the performance (it could be like 100x faster).

Answer (score 1):

Let's put some numbers here. You are dealing with images with a size of 200x185. Do you realize we are talking about 37000 features right? If we deal with gray levels. If we deal with RGB multiply that by 3. How many images are you using for training? Keep also in mind that SGD (Stochastic Gradient Descent, mini-batch size = 1) tend to be very slow for big datasets... Give us some numbers. How many training images and what is "slow". How much time for one epoch. Something else: programming languages, library (tensorflow, etc.), optimizer, etc. would help us in judging if your code is "slow" and can it be made faster.

Answer (score 0):

`batch size` is another param affect training time: higher size will help reduce time each epoch, but will require more epoch to have the same effiency like size=1

And if your network is deep (using CNN, etc), you should run on GPU